# Added AJAX controls to toolkit but can't add them to webpage, no smart tags

Tags: c#, ajax, visual-studio-2008

Added AJAX controls to my toolkit as per directions online.
They appear in the AJAX Toolkit tab in the toolbox just fine.
Try to add them to design view and does not work.
Tried selecting the textbox and clicking the smart tag to add the extender but there is not smart tag.

Googled and found suggestion to reset toolbox and re-add AJAX controls.
Did that and problem remains.

Any help is appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you added it to your page directives?

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
```

Comment: David,

Is that VB.net?  We're using C# -- do you know the equivalent thing to do in the .cs file?  I went to one of those sites that converts VB => C# but it wouldn't convert it for me.

Comment: This is not VB or C# specific. Stick it at the top of your .aspx page right below the `<%@ Page Lanauge="C#" blah blah blah %>` directive.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same exact issue recently.

The only solution that worked for me was downloading another version of the toolkit. It seems that some versions work better than others depending on your installation of visual studio, but overall I was not happy with the toolkit. Even though the extender option started to show up, some tools would work fine and others just wouldn't show up on my page even though they were adding in the designer.

Also make sure you add the script manager before adding any extenders.

In the end I ended up using dojo (http://www.dojotoolkit.org/) instead which gave me more flexibility even though it requires more hand coding.

Good luck